# Package Azure Cloud Service from command line like it is done in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, msbuild, azure-cloud-services, stylecop

I want to create a .cspkg file to deploy my existing web application as an azure cloud service. Visual Studio (2015) has this nifty button in the context menu of the Cloud Service I set up:

[image: VS Cloud Service Package Command]

This button does exactly what I want to achieve. It packages my application so that I can deploy it later on. But I have to get it to work on my build agent so I have to trigger this from either command line or powershell. I tried the following command that I found somewhere on the internet

```
msbuild ProjectName.ccproj /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Cloud-Test  /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:OutputPath=bin\ /p:PublishDir=bin\app
```

It works in general, but I get weird errors from the StyleCop.Analyzers I am using. However I don't have the same errors when packaging via Visual Studio.

So here's my question: Does anyone know what Visual Studio does exactly in the background, when I press the package button?

How do they create the .cspkg and can I do the same from command line/powershell?

EDIT:

As requested the following is the .ccproj file I'm trying to build. I only changed the project name and references for privacy and took out the configurations I wasn't using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>2.9</ProductVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{ade99ccd-7432-4939-b3cd-69a736c0801b}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Test.Cloud</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Test.Cloud</AssemblyName>
    <StartDevelopmentStorage>True</StartDevelopmentStorage>
    <Name>Test.Cloud</Name>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <UseIISExpressByDefault>False</UseIISExpressByDefault>
    <PackageEnableRemoteDebugger>False</PackageEnableRemoteDebugger>
    <UseEmulatorExpressByDefault>False</UseEmulatorExpressByDefault>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Cloud-Test' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Cloud-Test\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Items for the project -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <ServiceDefinition Include="ServiceDefinition.csdef" />
    <None Include="ServiceDefinition_Cloud-Prod.csdef">
      <DependentUpon>ServiceDefinition.csdef</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="ServiceDefinition_Cloud-Test.csdef">
      <DependentUpon>ServiceDefinition.csdef</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <ServiceConfiguration Include="ServiceConfiguration.Cloud-Prod.cscfg" />
    <ServiceConfiguration Include="ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg" />
    <ServiceConfiguration Include="ServiceConfiguration.Cloud-Test.cscfg" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Profiles" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PublishProfile Include="Profiles\TestlinieStaging.azurePubxml" />
    <PublishProfile Include="Profiles\PrototypProduction.azurePubxml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="Test.csproj">
      <Name>Test</Name>
      <Project>{b9e789aa-89a4-48c0-ac61-113085533066}</Project>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <RoleType>Web</RoleType>
      <RoleName>Test</RoleName>
      <UpdateDiagnosticsConnectionStringOnPublish>True</UpdateDiagnosticsConnectionStringOnPublish>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- Import the target files for this project template -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition=" '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' ">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <CloudExtensionsDir Condition=" '$(CloudExtensionsDir)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Windows Azure Tools\2.9\</CloudExtensionsDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(CloudExtensionsDir)Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RoleName>Yello.Web.Site</RoleName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration)=='Cloud-Test'">
    <TargetProfile>Cloud-Test</TargetProfile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>if exist "$(ProjectDir)ServiceDefinition_$(ConfigurationName).csdef" "$(VS120COMNTOOLS)..\IDE\tf.exe" checkout "$(ProjectDir)ServiceDefinition.csdef"
if exist "$(ProjectDir)ServiceDefinition_$(ConfigurationName).csdef" xcopy /Y "$(ProjectDir)ServiceDefinition_$(ConfigurationName).csdef" "$(ProjectDir)ServiceDefinition.csdef"</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I confirm that the problem still exists with above configuration. I'm using msbuild 14.0.25420.1 by the way.

As for the StyleCop Analyzers. I have them activated in the "Test" project I'm trying to package. They are using the same ruleset file as CodeAnalysis, which I modified. Specifically I deactivated the rule SA1027UseTabsCorrectly. I'm pretty confident I properly deactivated it, since it doesn't show up anymore other than in my case here. I'm using StyleCop Analyzers Version 1.0.0.

Comment: from  VS 2013 onwards MSbuild is part of Visual studio. so it should also do the same. style cop errors because you are validating those rules during build. You can disable with this msbuild parameter /p:StyleCopEnabled=false

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am validating the stylecop rules on purpose. It just seems that the command line version of msbuild doesn't acknowledge my custom stylecop rulset whereas the VS-triggered version does. Something seems to be missing and I don't know what

Comment: How do you custom and apply stylecop ruleset? Provide detail code of project file (ccproj).

Comment: I included more details as requested. Let me know if you still need more information. Thanks!

Comment: You may share the sample projects include sample code (for StyleCop Analysis) on the OneDrive.

Comment: Can you add one more argument "/p:TargetProfile=Cloud" or "/p:TargetProfile=Local" and then try again?

Comment: Has anyone figured out what the syntax is to manually do the "Package" step from a command line? Like the OP, I'm looking to have it done exactly how it is done in Visual Studio but am running into all kinds of errors trying to do so with MSBuild.

Comment: Is there an update for this ?